# Snipcart - possible to make a custom cart using React?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, snipcart

I am making a Next website, and added Snipcart.
The Snipcart UI embeds Vue, and has embedded images in it, and an external CSS file, which all in all add a ridiculous amount of time to my page load time.
I also don't quite like the UI, but that's a more minor issue as it can be customized.

So I was thinking if instead I can incorporate the cart's actual logic into my own React UI, and avoid all of the extra loading time while fully controlling how the cart looks and reacts to events.

I looked around Snipcart's documentation and saw there's actually a REST API, however it seems to be only for getting existing orders/products and such, not quite helpful for an active session.

I wonder if anyone tried this, or if the Snipcart cart's code is open source and available somewhere (I couldn't find it on their github, but I might have missed it).

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not possible at the moment, I'm on the Snipcart team, and we have plans to make our JavaScript SDK available as a NPM package eventually so that customers will be able to do custom carts with the technology they like. But, we're a small bootstrapped team, so it's still in the works.

But, we will soon be working on decreasing our footprint, we're aware that our bundle is large and could be optimized.

Comment: Thanks for the answer - looking forward to an SDK, Snipcart is pretty nifty